# Phonegap - HTML Tags not working on Email Composer Plugin

Tags: html, email, cordova, composer-php

I'm using Email Composer Plugin for my Cordova 2.5 app, it works, but I have some issues:

The tags img and table are not working, when I set an img, Gmail shows me "obj", and when I use tables, it just doesnt tabulate it as a table.

Finally, when I try to use Outlook as the app for sending the email, the destination and subject are correct, but the body field is empty.